# Name cannot begin with the /r character

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

Reading an XML file is giving me the following error.

> Name cannot begin with the /r character

Using a pretty normal call to load the file.
    XDocument.Load(fileName);

Answer (score 1):

It turned out I had an errant < character in my file.

I was commenting out certain child nodes and when erasing one of the comment tags, I left an extra < in the file.

```
<node>
    <!-- <child /> --><
    <child />
    <child />
</node>
```